# Is it bad to access the constructor prototype within the constructor?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, constructors, prototyping

Most places where I have seen prototypes defined for a constructor it was done like so.

```
var Person = function(){
    this.stuff = stuff;
}
Person.prototype.doSomething = function(){console.log("something")}
var john = new Person();
```

But to me, coming from Java it seems more intuitive to define it directly inside the constructor.

```
var Person = function(){
    this.stuff = stuff;
Person.prototype.doSomething = function(){console.log("something")}
}
var john = new Person();
```

But the fact that I have never seen it done that way before makes me wonder if there is something wrong with doing it that way. Does it cause any problems I haven't foreseen?

Comment: Will it execute?  I've never tried it this way; it might be possible that you can't modify the prototype until the constructor has fully executed.

Comment: Also, note that modifying the prototype causes all instances of the object to be modified, not just this instance. So putting it into the constructor of an object doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, "modifying the prototype causes all instances of the object to be modified" not quite. You're modifying the parent prototype that all instances already refer to. You're not actually modifying *any* of the instances generated from the function.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Yes, I get that.  However, since all instances inherit from the prototype anyway, your observation is probably a distinction without a difference.  As I said before, doing this in the constructor is probably a bad idea.

Comment: The distinction does make a difference, at the very least, obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) will return a different answer. They also have different uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire point of setting a function on a "constructor" in JavaScript is so that it's set for the prototype chain when an instance is accessed.

<sub>Example A</sub>

```
function Foo() {...}
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {...}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(); //references the shared function on the constructor
```

As an alternative, functions can be set directly on instances in the constructor.

<sub>Example B</sub>

```
function Foo() {
  this.bar = function () {...};
}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(); //references the function set directly on the instance
```

The difference between these two methods is in how many functions are created.

Generating a thousand instances of `Foo` in example A will have *exactly one* `bar` method defined and used for *all* instances.

Generating a thousand instances of `Foo` in example B will have **one thousand** methods created. One for each instance. This can be useful for accessing scoped variables, but comes with the obvious performance cost.

---

If instead you add the function to the prototype *inside* the constructor...

<sub>Example C: (don't ever do this)</sub>

```
function Foo() {
  Foo.prototype.bar = function () {...};
}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(); //references the shared function on the constructor
```

**You get the worst of both methods**. You're completely unable to make use of scoped variables, because the prototype is shared, so every instance will overwrite the function and scope that's available, and you're generating a new function for each instance, *and* you're throwing out all the existing functions.

Don't ever write JavaScript in that manner.

---

**tl;dr:**

> Is it bad to access the constructor prototype within the constructor?

Yes

Comment: good answer. but wouldn't trying to access `Foo` (or `Foo.prototype`) within its own definition throw an error?

Comment: @chharvey, why should it? You're setting a property on an object just like any other object (remember, in JS, functions are first-class objects).

Comment: right but I thought you can't access an object while defining it. such as `var obj = { foo: 'bar', qux: obj.foo }`. but maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @chharvey, JS object literal notation has nothing to do with being able to access a function within a function. Additionally, it's absolutely necessary to be able to call a function within itself if you're ever going to do recursion. Furthermore, while instantiating an object instance from a function, you have access to `this` which is the new instance being generated, so the example  you've shown would be written as: `var obj = new function () { this.foo = 'bar'; this.qux = this.foo };`.

Comment: That is an awesome answer, however I'm confused by the result of this code in relation to what you said.


`var Person = function(){
 Person.prototype.doSomething = function(){console.log("something")}
}

var john = new Person()
console.log(john.hasOwnProperty(doSomething()))`


returns this:


`console.log(john.prototype.hasOwnProperty(doSomething()))
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`

meaning the instance doesn't have the property, even though it can access it. Sorry code in this comment is formatted badly.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` takes a string parameter, which is why you're getting the wrong results.

Comment: When I put it in parenthesis it returns false instead. I believe if I am remembering what this thread was about correctly, that still contradicts your statements. Sorry if I am mistaken, I only woke up half an hour ago and still feel a little fuzzy.

Comment: @Supetorus, you wrote `john.prototype.hasOwnProperty(doSomething())` which is incorrect on many levels. `john` does not have a `prototype` property, `Person` does. Additionally, prototype properties are not **own** properties. `'doSomething' in john` would be the appropriate way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your original answer. Near the end you said "and you're generating a new function for each instance", doesn't this mean that john should have the function itself? Or did you mean something different?

Comment: @Supetorus, every time `new Person` gets called you'd be instantiating a new function, assigning it to the prototype, blowing away the old one. So no, the `john` instance would never have the function itself.

Comment: Ok I think it makes sense now, thanks for the help.